# make single concatenated string from rows in BigQuery to pass later to python

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple table:

| order_id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | apple |
| 123 | orange |
| 123 | pear |
| 124 | lemon |
| 124 | pear |
| 125 | peach |
| 125 | apple |

I want to get a single concatenated string from rows by a query in BigQuery to pass it later to python as a list:

| order_id | item_names |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 'apple', 'orange', 'pear' |
| 124 | 'lemon', 'pear' |
| 125 | 'peach', 'apple' |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select order_id, string_agg("'" || item_name || "'", ', ') item_name
from  your_table
group by order_id
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]